# NetCore AutoMapper Nested Child stopped in first child

Tags: .net, .net-core, automapper

I have entity like this

```
public partial class EntityClass {
   public int id {get;set;}
   public virtual ICollection<EntityClass> Children {get;set;}
}
```

and dto like this

```
public class DtoClass {
   public int id {get;set;}
   public List<DtoClass> Children {get;set;}
}
```

I also have profile class

```
public class MyProfile : Profile{
  public MyProfile(){
    CreateMap<EntityClass, DtoClass>().ReverseMap();
  {
}
```

and use automapper like this

```
dtoQueryable = entityQueryable.ProjectTo<DtoClass>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider);
```

in entity result like this

```
Parent
- Child1
- Child2
  - Grandchild1
```

but after mapping, dto result like this

```
Parent
- Child 1
- Child 2
```

it is not map grandchild, how can I get until grandchild?

Comment: How would you do it without AM, in an EF LINQ query? Does that even work?

Comment: what do you mean? I use AutoMapper here

Comment: That's not relevant. You _have_ to understand what's going on underneath. You need to do a little research. There are _many_ similar questions.